# MYSQL variable in function

Tags: mysql-5.5

Can anybody tell why the value of `@URlID` is always -1 even when i know the query will return a result? I have tried any possible type of variables and any possible way of inserting into the variable yet no effect.

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION getShortURLID(URL varchar(1200))
    RETURNS INT 
    DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA 
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    BEGIN
        SET @newShortURL:=NULL;
        SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(URL, "http://", ""), "https://", ""), "www.", ""), '/', 1) INTO @newShortURL ;
    set @URLID:= -1;
    set @URLID := (SELECT ifnull(id,0) FROM url_productivity WHERE url = @newShortURL LIMIT 1);

    IF @URLID <=> 0 then
        INSERT INTO urls(url) VALUES(@newShortURL); 
        RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
    ELSE 
        RETURN @URLID ;
    END IF;
    END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
set @URLID := (SELECT ifnull(id,0) FROM url_productivity WHERE url = @newShortURL LIMIT 1);
```

isn't returning any rows at all, therefore `@URLID` retains the value set in the preceding line i.e. -1.